# How do I load a Kendo UI grid Add/Edit window without the grid?

Tags: datagrid, dialog, kendo-ui

Kendo UI makes it very easy to use MVVM when using a grid to add or edit records by automating much of the window usage.

This is great as long as you have the grid on your screen, but what if I want to add or edit a record on a page where the grid is not available?  How would I call the same edit window and get all the same error checking, binding, etc?

Comment: If theres no grid, how does a user select the record to be edited

Comment: I would already know the ID of the record to edit.

Comment: I might consider using a custom edit page, since you said you have the ID already I assume your coming into this edit page from a new page. Throw some labels and textboxes on the page, pass the model into the view and take it from there

Answer (score 0):

Your question is more about general MVC development. Take a look [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/examining-the-edit-methods-and-edit-view).